# Extract html part from string (include plain text and html part) using java

Tags: java, html, email, jsoup, jakarta-mail

I have an inputstream from email which can be converted to string like this:

```
String content = "Hello world!\n"+
                 "Thank you!\n"+
                 "\n"+
                 "<html>\n" +
                 "<head>\n" +
                 "\t<meta id=\"leadId\" name=\"leadId\" content=\"6778130\"/>\n" +
                 "\t<title>testing</title>\n" +
                 "</head>\n" +
                 "<body>\n" +
                 "\t<span>testing - 20200727</span>\n" +
                 "</body>\n" +
                 "</html>"+
                 "\n" + 
                 "Have a good day!";
```

I wanna extract HTML part from this string, the result I expect is like:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta id="leadId" name="leadId" content="6778130"/>
    <titletesting</title>
</head>
<body>
    <span>testing - 20200727</span>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried Jsoup before, but it didn't work for me.
Does anyone know other solutions to it?
Can I use javax.mail for it (the inputstream itself)? If so, how can I do that? Could you provide an example?

Comment: That’s a strange e-mail body.  It looks like someone concatenated all the parts of a multipart/alternative message.  If so, it would make sense to just read the body of one MIME part.

Comment: Try `String html = content.replaceFirst("(?s)^.*(<html>.*</html>).*$", "$1");`

Answer (score 0):

My approach - use a regex to extract the bit of text you're interested in.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

```java
 Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<html>.*</html>");
 Matcher m = p.matcher(inputString);
 String html = m.group();
```

You could then use `JSoup.parse(html);` to parse the html and navigate the elements. (Or us HtmlUnit if you want to navigate the document using XPaths).